# Problem regarding Buoyancy forces and Archimedes principle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statics, buoyancy, fluid-statics

A thin-walled container of mass $m$ floats vertically at the separation surface of the two liquids of density $ρ_1$ and $ρ_2$  . The whole mass of the container is concentrated in the part of height $h$.

The question is to determine the immersion depth $h'$of the container in the lower liquid if the bottom of the container has a thickness $h$ and an area $S$ and if the container itself is filled with the liquid of density $ρ_1$.

[image]

I applied the fundamental principle of the statics on the container

$Balance$ $Sheet$:

The weight of the container ($-mg$)

The buoyancy force applied by the fluid with density $ρ_2$ ($ρ_2gSh$)

The weight of the fluid with density  $ρ_1$  (-$ρ_2gSh'$)

I summed up the forces and set them to zero and find my $h'$

but then  realised that the fluid with density  $ρ_1$  applied also a buoyoncy force on the top of the container , and the fluid with density  $ρ_2$  applied a buoyoncy force on the other fluid.

Where's the problem ?

Comment: $m$ is the mass pf the container which is concentrated in the black part with thickness $h$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can completely neglect the part of the container that sticks out into the liquid with density $\rho_1$ because its weight and its buoyancy cancel each other out exactly.

The balance for the *rest* of the container becomes:

$$\text{weight}=\text{buoyancy}$$

Assume the container has constant cross-section $S$, then with $mg$ the weight of the container *plus* the weight of the material between the bottom and $h$ ($^*$ proof below the fold):
$$h'S\rho_1g+mg=(h'+h)S\rho_2g$$

---

$^*$

[image: Buoyancy]

$$W=mg+(h'+h'')\rho_1Sg$$
$$B=h''\rho_1Sg+(h'+h)\rho_2Sg$$
$$W=B$$
$$mg+(h'+h'')\rho_1Sg=h''\rho_1Sg+(h'+h)\rho_2Sg$$
Now decompose $W$ and $B$ into part above and below the liquid separation line:
$$W_1=h'\rho_1Sg+mg\tag{1}$$
$$B_1=(h+h')\rho_2Sg$$
$$W_2=h''\rho_1Sg$$
$$B_2=h''\rho_1Sg$$
$$\implies W_2=B_2$$
With:
$$W=W_1+W_2$$
$$B=B_1+B_2$$
$$W=B$$
Or:
$$W_1+W_2=B_1+B_2$$
$$\implies W_1=B_1$$
Which with substitution gives us the expression above the fold.

Comment: $(h'+h)Aρ_2g$ is $buoyancy$ and the weight of fluid 1 is $h′Aρ_1g$ what about $hAρ_2g$ ? and wheres the weight  of the container ($mg$)

Comment: Your problem states: *"The whole mass of the container is concentrated in the part of height $h$."* I therefore assumed the container  was massless. If not, add $mg$ to the LHS of the equation but then you need to know $A$ to get a solution.

Comment: yes but where did $hAρ_2g$ came from ?

Comment: I've edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: I still have one problem , I don't understand where did $hSρ_2g$ ? what is it $buoyancy=(h′+h)Sρ_2g$ and the total weight is the weight of the container plus the weight of the fluid 1 so $weight= $